# .NET5 is unable to run an application built for .NETCore.App 3.1.0

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-5

I attempt to run our existing applications on .NET5 environtment.
But I got an error below:

> It was possible to find any compatible framework version
>
> The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
>
> - The following frameworks were found:
>
>   5.0.8 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>
> You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
>
> The specified framework can be found at:
>
> - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=win81-x64

I tried to execute commands like this:

> MyApp.exe

I wonder that .NET5 is not compatible previous .NETCore versions.
I suppose that both of old .NETCore app and old .NETFramework app are able to run on .NET5 environment.
I understand that .NET5 is an environment that unified .NETFramework and .NETCore.
So I believe that can execute both app on a unified platform.

Is my understanding incorrect?

Excuse me to be asking such a basic question, but could you tell me that?

Comment: open [application-name].runtimeconfig.json, inside `runtimeOptions` section insert `"rollForwardOnNoCandidateFx": 2` and try again

Comment: An exact match on the major version is required.  It can be forced, use the [rollForward property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection).

Comment: Hi, @JL0PD . 
Thanks for your advice.
I tried adding the configuration to my application, then it works. The application could be executed without error.